# Assign key to default button option when shown information message in vscode extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I am creating an extension in VSCode that will close all open text documents when you click the option "Yes" in the `vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Want to close?", "Yes", "No)`.

Pressing the "Yes" button will work fine but I want the "Enter" key on the keyboard to do the same? How can I listen for keystrokes when I register a command? Is it possible?

Here is my code right now:

```
  context.subscriptions.push(
    vscode.commands.registerCommand(
      "close-tabs",
      async (inputValue?: string) => {
        const { activeTextEditor } = vscode.window;

        if (!activeTextEditor) {
          vscode.window.showInformationMessage("No active text editor");
          return;
        }

        const answer = await vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Want to close tabs?", "Yes", "No");

        if (answer === "Yes") {
          vscode.commands.executeCommand("openEditors.closeAll");
        }
        // ON_ENTER: I was thinking an if case here that checks if enter has been pressed and also executes the command above? 
      }
    )
  );
```

To reiterate. How can I choose the "Yes" option when pressing the "Enter" key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `InformationMessage` box is not modal, it doesn't get focus when it appears.

I'm afraid you would have to make it modal - which in your case might be acceptable - to get the behaviour you want:

`const answer = await vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Want to close tabs?", { modal: true }, "Yes", "No");`

Then the message box's first button is automatically given focus and <kbd>Enter</kbd> will trigger it.